# how to remove black color of popup window in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, popupwindow

hi All i have popup screen with background image .image is display with black border .so how can i remove the additional black color of popup screen ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the above code given by @Mugur, but still you will end up with heaving border of the popup screen. To remove the border use the below code

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder( new XYEdges(), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT);
            this.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: what's this ? really android?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
  // Clear the default translucent background

  PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
  popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Or try this...

```
  popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: Is this BlackBerry Java?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PopupScreen scr = new PopupScreen() {
   protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
      int color = 0xff0000;
      g.setColor(color);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
   }
}
```

This should set the background color to red(ff0000).

---

EDIT:

```
PopupScreen scr = new PopupScreen(new VerticalFieldManager() {
       protected void paint(Graphics g) {
          int color = g.getColor();
          g.setColor(0xff0000);
          g.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
          g.setColor(color);
          super.paint(g);
       }
});
```

Comment: thax Mugur . this code cant help me ..if u have another solution than plz help me .

Comment: i m using    setBackground (BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground (Color.WHITE, 0));  but i still get little Black border .

Answer (score 0):

try creating your own custom popscreen and override methods
you can create your own custom background using paint method

try trial and error it will surely work this way

To create a custom popscreen all you need to do is create a class and then extend popScreen

Answer (score 0):

You need to override applyTheme and make it do nothing, to avoid the black border on a popup:

```
protected void applyTheme(){}
```